# security for REST api implemented with spring-mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, restful-authentication

I am reading up about the different views on REST api security both here at SO and over at other places, and given that i am using spring-mvc, makes me wonder in what ways will a url pattern/user-session based security wrong for REST. The scenario where each request carries a cookie is not so different from it carrying some access token/url hash. There will be a notion of a session as marked by the lifetime of the access token , which i think should timeout if i am using it from a browser based client